# Apportionment: Where is the actual language for "the method known as the method of equal proportions" in the U.S.C.?

Tags: united-states, congress, census

In the United States Congress, there are two legislative bodies: the House of Representatives and the Senate.  These two bodies are structured differently from the very beginning in Article 1 of the [U.S. Constitution](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript) in that the Senate represents each U.S. state equally (two senators for each state) and House represents populations roughly equally: *"Representatives ... shall be apportioned among the several States which may be included within this Union, according to their respective Numbers... The actual Enumeration shall be made ... within every subsequent Term of ten Years, in such Manner as they shall by Law direct."*

So big states (w.r.t. population) get more representatives than do small states.  The Constitution does not spell out how many total representatives there are in the House nor exactly the manner that the apportionment shall determine how many each state gets.  It's just that every 10 years, we **must** have a [Census](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census.html) for which the primary Constitutional purpose is to determine how the U.S. House of Representatives is apportioned among the now 50 U.S. states.  The data from the Census gets used in a variety of ways and purposes, but this is the original primary purpose of the U.S. Decennial Census.  It's a big deal.

(I would presume, in the European Union, that they have the same issue, but maybe [settle the issue differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_in_the_European_Parliament).)

So then, the specific number of U.S. representatives and the specific manner of proportionately distributing their seats to the various states is a matter of federal law (one notch lower than the Constitution) and is spelled out in [U.S.C. Title 2](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2011-title2/html/USCODE-2011-title2.htm).  Well, not really completely spelled out, hence this question.

Okay, I know and understand what *"the method known as the method of equal proportions"* is.  It's also known as the [Huntington-Hill Method](https://www.census.gov/history/www/reference/apportionment/methods_of_apportionment.html) and is referred to as "the method known as the method of equal proportions" in §2a and §2b of [U.S.C. Title 2](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2011-title2/html/USCODE-2011-title2.htm).

[There is also some useful history to read](https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-apportion2) but I want to see the actual document in law that spells it out.  Even if it was a report transmitted to Congress circa 1941, I would like to see what a federal judge would be saying that "this is what the law is" and I cannot find that.

Where is this *"method of equal proportions"* actually spelled out in the actual law?  I cannot find it.  I understand how the H-H method works and I have read a little history about it.

Comment: yeah, there's always a downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing legally authoritative (e.g. codified regulations) beyond 2 U.S.C. §§ 2a and 2b, except for the legislative history of those acts.

In the case of Section 2a, this is the legislative history of 46 Stat. 26, c. 28, § 22 (June 18, 1929), 54 Stat. 162, c. 152 (Apr. 25, 1940), 55 Stat. 761, c. 470, § 1 (Nov. 15, 1941), and Pub.L. 104-186, Title II, § 201, 110 Stat. 1724 (Aug. 20, 1996).

In the case of Section 2b, this is the legislative history of 55 Stat. 762, c. 470, § 2(a) (Nov. 15, 1941).

But primarily, the relevant legislative history is the legislative history of the 1941 act mentioned above that introduced the concept.

Only one case has litigated § 2b and it does not address the mechanics of the equal proportions method. While many cases have been litigated under § 2a (59 annotations in some cases with more than one annotation from a single case), none of them addressed the meaning of the words "method of equal proportions". The census bureau, however, [notes two cases](https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector/congressional-apportionment/about/historical-perspective.html) that it looks to: *Department of Commerce v. Montana*, [112 S.Ct. 1415](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/503/442) (1992) and *Franklin v. Massachusetts* [112 S.Ct. 2767](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/112784/franklin-v-massachusetts/) (1992). The court in the first case found that the method adopted by Congress was constitutional and that its meaning was clarified by the National Academy of Science Committee report referenced by Congress in the legislative history involved in adopting the 1941 Act. The second case only touches on the issue tangentially because that issue was mooted by the resolution of the first case.

The meaning of the words "method of equal proportions" has never been reduced to a federal regulation.

The Congressionally intended meaning of the term method of equal proportions has always been sufficiently clear to avoid all disputes over it, even though it is not, for example, defined in Black's Law Dictionary.

The U.S. Census Bureau has, however, explained how the "method of equal proportions" works on multiple occasions in [non-authoritative documents like press releases](https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector/congressional-apportionment/about/computing.html), and those together with secondary sources explaining it, could be offered up to prove it if necessary.

Comment: **How can that be???**  There is a helluva lot of gap between *"the method known as the method of equal proportions"* and the actual algorithm.  And our history shows that there were several other algorithms used previously to 1941.  Of course, as these seats are meted out, there will be the state in line to get the 435th seat, but just misses it.  They might be pissed off and, if another method gives them that seat instead of the other state that actually ***did*** receive the last apportioned seat, if the method isn't spelled out in law, what does a federal judge use to adjudicate?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Nobody has litigated it because nobody has believed that they could win. It is spelled out in the law with a term whose meaning is clear enough and a host of experts on historical practice could testify to that effect. Also, courts have held that the President has broad discretion in implementing the task of taking the census and calculating reapportionment to the extent that there is any ambiguity. This situation isn't terribly unusual in the law.

Comment: I understand that *"The U.S. Census Bureau has, however, explained how the "method of equal proportions" works on multiple occasions in non-authoritative documents "*, but what does a federal judge use to adjudicate litigation if some state sues right after a Census?  And who says that it's the Census Bureau that actually runs the algorithm?  The Census Bureau gives us the numbers, but what official act or "ceremony" performs the calculation and declares the result of Apportionment?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson A judge isn't limited to looking at the authoritative enactments. The mechanics of who does what when are mostly set forth in 13 U.S.C. § 141. Especially 13 U.S.C. § 141(b).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson How can that be? Consider that there's no definition of "marriage" in the Constitution or Code, despite the vast number of laws that relate to it. Which eventually led to SCOTUS ruling that despite centuries of tradition, it's not just man-woman.

Comment: Well, @Barmar , some people might say that the Court was unlawfully legislating from the bench.  Not that it's never happened before.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson True, but it's the lack of definition that makes that possible. The point is that lawmakers aren't like mathematicians or computer programmers, they don't define everything rigidly. Much language is just taken from accepted usage.

Comment: In the case of marriage, it was statutorily defined in the Defense of Marriage Act, and many courts and ultimately the U.S. Supreme Court, held that the 14th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution rendered that statutory definition unconstitutional.

Comment: Okay, then @Barmar I know that lawmakers are not all mathematicians or programmers, but this is pretty fundamental.  I also know from the history I could read, that Prof. Huntington did a lotta lobbying in Congress to get them to check out his proposed method and he got other mathematicians of fame (like von Neumann) to endorse it.  So when this actual algorithm was accepted by Congress, how did the actual mechanics get codified?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson What you see is the sum total of what codified his method. From the legislative history, we know that this is what Congress meant when it said that, and a judge asked to clarify could resort to that legislative history.

Comment: *Grrrrr!*  I'm not entirely satisfied (it's no one's fault here).  I just wanna see [what we see at this page on the government website](https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector/congressional-apportionment/about/computing.html) codified in ***real*** United States Law somewhere.  If these details are not codified, I just think that some shitty litigation will occur somewhere sometime.  It should be mechanical.  But the mechanics should also be well defined, ***and they ain't***.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The details on the Census website are indeed not codified in a statute or regulation. Litigation might occur sometime (although there are issues over the extent and context in which it is justiciable - i.e. without the jurisdiction of courts as opposed to being a political question). But the fact that the meaning of a word isn't codified in an official definition doesn't mean that they are not well defined. Courts routinely apply binding law that is not codified in excruciating detail by resorting to non-authoritative secondary sources, even on major issues.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson one thing about law that people sometimes don't appreciate is that when everyone understands what is meant by a word or phrase, the legislature may not even think of the _possibility_ that it should be further defined, let alone actually enact an explicit definition.  It's only later, when people who weren't around at the time and therefore do not take the context for granted, start saying things like "hey, wait a minute, how do we know that this really means?" that serious questions arise that may need to be decided by a court or clarified by the legislature.

Comment: Well @phoog , what you say may be true, but it's not acceptable.  This is about being a well-defined mathematical procedure.  And before 1940 there were ***other*** methods used.  What are they called?  The *"the method known as the method of **un**equal proportions"*?  They ***all*** wanna be equal proportions, but some algorithms do a better job than others.  We have this problem right now with Ranked-Choice Voting in the United States where FairVote and RCVRC are forcing us to ***assume*** that *"RCV"* means a specific method (and a flawed method) that they promote.  It's dishonest.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Other methods focused, for example, on absolute deviation amounts from the average rather than a proportions. They sought to equalize something other than proportions (i.e. the average number of seats in Congress per voter).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson if you find it unacceptable then your best course of action is probably to start a letter writing campaign to members of congress to call for the enactment of a specific definition.  I suspect, however, that members of congress won't give it much priority because (as this answer notes) the meaning is clear.  Everyone knows what it means or can find out with minimal effort.  The procedure _is_ in fact well defined.  The benefits of enacting the definition into law are therefore small, while the costs are relatively large.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The historically-used apportionment algorithms are described [on census.gov](https://www.census.gov/history/www/reference/apportionment/methods_of_apportionment.html).  There was also a time or two when Congress made *ad hoc* additions of House seats without going through the proper mathematical formalities.

Comment: I know about the census.gov information.  The purpose of the questions was about where that method is prescribed by law.  It seems pretty awful goddam important for that to have changed circa 1940 without the record pointing out where Congress acted to change it to that specific method.  I also am aware of the [Alabama paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox#Alabama_paradox) and some goofy stuff when Hawaii and Alaska were added to the Union. It's just beyond me why this method is not spelled out in legislation since there is lots of other complex legislation.